# Callback notation in a Mediator

Tags: c#, lambda, callback, mediator

I'm implementing a Mediator and I'd like to simplify the callback notation a bit.

My mediator has `Register` and `Notify` methods :

```
public class Mediator {
    private Dictionary<Messages, Action<object>> registeredCallback;

    public void Register(Messages message, Action callback) {
        registeredCallback[message] = callback;
    }

    public void Notify(Messages message, object parameter) {
        callback(parameter);
    }

    public Mediator() {
        registeredCallback = new Dictionary<Messages, Action<object>>();
    }
}
```

It uses a `Messages` enumerator to sanitize events between registered objects, for example :

```
public enum Messages {
    UserCreated,
    UserDeleted,
    UserChangedPassword
};
```

So far, so good. However, when I use this mediator I'm making ugly callback definitions :

```
mediator.Register(Messages.UserCreated, (object user) => GreetUser(((User)user).name));
```

with the following `User`:

```
public class User {
    public string name;
}
```

**Type casting? *Lambda expressions?*** This looks obviously filthy. How can I clean this up? Is my architecture at fault?

Comment: I think it's the first time I see someone complain that Lambda are filthy :P Honestly I think your code is good. Sometimes, type casting is necessary.

Comment: I find lambdas filthy because _they don't have a name_. They don't explain what they do, they aren't reusable... I think that's confusing in real-life situations? Thank you for the compliment, though!

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not real C# and the code is broken. You use the `registeredCallbacks[message]` in a loop but the value is an `Action<object>` and it cannot be enumerated.

Comment: @t3chb0t I'm actually using a custom `MultiDictionary` which stores multiple callbacks in a `HashSet<Action<object>>` for each message. I didn't include it in my example to simplify a bit. I removed the loop, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: _I didn't include it in my example to simplify a bit._ This is usually a mistake becasue if your code isn't real then what is the point of reviewing it? People will sugest improvements that you either already have implemented or are irrelevant. It doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Do you have to use an enum for some reason? Why not create a `UserCreated` class with a `User` data member? Then you can just register like `(UserCreated msg) => GreetUser(msg.User.Name)`

Comment: @t3chb0t I tried to focus my code review request because the problem was really on the callback invoking, not the callback storing. Any improvements suggested would likely not have been about storing one or ten thousand callbacks per message, but _how_ these callbacks are invoked.
However if code-reviewers expect to see a full code implementation on CR then I'll provide that in future questions — thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @default.kramer I'm using an enum because I'll likely have a lot more messages to create later, possibly not related to users, and I don't want to make a class for each one. I especially don't want to have my other objects depend on these classes : one change in a message class would mean I have to change **all** the callbacks pertaining to that message.

Comment: This could be a great question, if you'd post the actual code instead of a simplified example. If you take a look at the [help/on-topic], you'll notice we don't do well with examplified code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about making the `Register` method generic?

```
public class Mediator
{
    private Dictionary<Messages, Action<object>> registeredCallback =
        new Dictionary<Messages, Action<object>>();

    public void Register<TParam>(Messages message, Action<TParam> callback)
    {
        registeredCallback[message] = p => callback((TParam)p);
    }

    public void Notify(Messages message, object parameter)
    {
        callback(parameter);
    }
}
```

The typecasting is done inside the `Register` method, making it invisible to any class using it.

You can also change signature of the `GreetUser` method so that it takes a `User` instead of a `string` as a parameter. By doing so you can call `Register` like this:

```
mediator.Register<User>(Messages.UserCreated, GreetUser);
```

Comment: Using a generic `Register` method is the best solution for this. It works perfectly with a method taking the same object type as argument. Thank you so much for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Since your comment said you didn't like lambdas, let me propose something!

You could use an interface, let's say `IMediatorCallBack`. Then, you would need to create a class for each callback. It may look like more trouble than it's worth, but if you have a lot of callbacks, it might be worth it.

```
public interface IMediatorCallBack 
{
    void Execute(object obj);
}

internal class UserCreatedMediatorCallBack : IMediatorCallBack
{
    public void Execute(object obj)
    {
        //At this point, you know that the callback is called by the mediator, so just cast it.
        var user = (User)obj;
        //etc..
    }
}
```

Notice that the class is `internal`. I think that's the way to go since it's pretty weird that we cast the `object` to `User` right away.

Then you could use your `Dictionary<Messages,IMediatorCallBack>`, which "talks" a little bit more.

I'm not 100% sure it's a better solution, but you wanted something without lambdas, there it is :)

Comment: I don't have a lot of callbacks, but I do have a lot of messages in my `enum`, so implementing a callback class for each message only to have it used once or twice is a bit too much.
+1 for the interface though, I didn't think of that and it might be of use later.